# Old game; npc gets angry if you destroy sign

Tags: game-identification

I'm pretty sure I remember playing a game years ago in my childhood where you can destroy the sign posts in the game (a la several Zelda games) and there being an npc who makes the signs and gets angry at you if you've destroyed any signs (or perhaps just angry if you destroy a sign next to him)... but I can't remember what game it was, and my hour of trying Google and DuckDuckGo has been fruitless. Anyone know of such a game? If my memory is correct, it is not progression-related, but just a goofy easter-egg-like moment.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Unfortunately, [ID of games from memory & without media from the game itself is considered off-topic here.](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10197/4797) We have a [list of alternative resources](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13525/4797) for such questions. If you recall any Speculative Fiction elements in the game (Sci-Fi, Fantasy, Magic/Supernatural, etc.), your question may fall within the scope of our sister site [scifi.se] SE, which allows SF game ID questions. Consider posting there, but check their [ID guidelines](//scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957) first.

Answer (score 1):

Another round of search engine attempts, and I think I found it:
https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Average_Middle-Aged_Man

Tho if anyone else reads this thread and is like, "Oh! You probably mean " then I'd still be really curious.